# What other than mappings and abbreviations can change the text I'm typing?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, filetype-tex, abbreviations

##### The question

When editing TeX files (to do so, I use [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)) if I've discovered that if I write  `lll` in insert mode, I get  `\ell`.

How do I find why this is happening?

##### My research

I thought "ok, I'll find out where this mapping or abbreviation is and whther vimtex or something else creates it".

I've checked `:ab lll` and all `:*map lll`, and the culprit turns out to be `lmap`, as the output of `:verbose lmap lll` is the following:

```
Kitty keyboard protocol: Cleared
l  l           * L
        Last set from ~/.vimrc line 654
```

And that line is where the following function is defined,

```
for c in range(char2nr('A'), char2nr('Z'))
    exe 'lnoremap ' . nr2char(c+32) . ' ' . nr2char(c)
    exe 'lnoremap ' . nr2char(c) . ' ' . nr2char(c+32)
endfor
```

which I took from [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Insert-mode_only_Caps_Lock) eons ago (and which comes with `autocmd InsertLeave * set iminsert=0` too).

But how is that causing the behavior I described above? And why only when `filetype` is `tex`???

Well the answer is that it is not, because if I delete that stuff the issue persists. After all, the output of `:verbose lmap lll` is not really telling me that `lll` is mapped to anything. Just that `l` is, and that's ok. Indeed, deleting the `for` loop above, `:verbose lmap lll` too gives no result.

So I'm left with `:ab lll` and all of `:*map lll` giving no output.

Where does this behavior come from?

Comment: Do you have a snippet plugin like [emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) or [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten about this. However, [yes, it's vim-snippets's UltiSnips snippet for TeX](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/1049d2425b6d270621b48e110de37d5467a2a621/UltiSnips/tex.snippets#L387).

```
snippet lll "l" Aw
\ell
endsnippet
```

---

Eventually, [I pushed a fix](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/commit/b0721103adf752ee1f724cb7c0c363bac1243e47).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: @Enlicc Maybe could you accept your own answer (you can do that two days after you post the answer). This will make the question rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt, thanks. I've linked the fix I pused to the repo.